# Parametros anidados en VB.Net y SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Saludos a todos, estoy haciendo una aplicación en VB.NET y SQL Server.
Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que me recupera todas las columnas de una tabla pasando como parámetro la contraseña, el detalle es que necesito guardar los datos recuperados para enviarlo como parámetro a otro procedimiento almacenado.

Alguna idea me pueden dar, se los agradecería bastante.

Es la parte de código para iniciar sesión.

```
Public Function validaUsuario(ByVal dts As vusuario) As Boolean
        Try
            conectar()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("pro_recupera_usuario")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = con

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dts.gpassword)

            Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.HasRows = True Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return False
        Finally
            desconectar()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Código que uso desde el formulario

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAceptar.Click

        Try
            Dim dts As New vusuario
            Dim func As New fusuario

            dts.gpassword = Trim(txtPassword.Text)
            If func.validaUsuario(dts) = True Then
                MsgBox("Existe usuario")
            Else
                MsgBox("No existe usuario")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Por ahora solo me da el mensaje de "Existe el usuario".

pero ahí necesito hacer una comparación de los datos recuperados para saber que formulario mostrar posteriormente ya que tengo 3 tipos de formularios:  A(admin), B(lideres) y C(usuarios)

Finalmete, ésta es la consulta donde ocupo el dato recuperado:

```
Public Function mostrar() As DataTable
        Try
            conectar()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("pro_compras_ConsultaxVendedor")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_vendedor", 8)

            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(dt)
                Return dt
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            desconectar()
        End Try
    End Function
```

En el lugar del número 8 de esta fila:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_vendedor", 8)
```

pasaría el valor del usuario que pertenece la contraseña.

El procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente:

```
create procedure pro_recupera_usuario
  @p1 integer(8) 
 as
  select PK_id_usuario, nombre_usuario, sucursal_usuario, estatus_usuario
   from tblUsuario
   where password= @p1;
```

Espero darme a entender y ojalá me puedan ayudar. GRACIAS

Comment: Hay un problema en tu logica o algo que no estas explicando. Como validas la contraseña contra la que tiene el usuario, si no pasas el codigo de usuario? o tu sistema solo toma contraseñas sin usuarios?

Comment: solo se pasa como parámetro la contraseña, a partir de ésta se obtiene el usuario y otros datos.

Comment: No es recomendable, a menos que tu asignes las contraseñas. Que pasaria si un admin y un usuario tienen la misma contraseña? que menu deberia de mostrar?

Comment: De echo es una contraseña que se asigna y se cambia de forma periódica a los usuarios.

Comment: La logica me parece que esta mal, Porque no mejor haces un procedimiento almacenado que tome la contraseña y devuelva el nombre,id,etc. En el SP la consulta seria algo asi como SELECT * FROM TABLA where contraseña = "datodelusuario"??

Comment: o sea que 4 usuarios (por decir algo) tienen la misma pass.. y tu no sabes cual hizo que cosa, porque solo tenes un usuario generico? y ademas, como les asignas las pass a mano, tienen que tenerla anotada, lo cual la hace mas insegura todavia? ok... entonces tu SP debe devolver el codigo de usuario, o null si la pass esta mal, y se soluciona tu problema.. que es mucho mas grave de lo que pensas

Comment: Si quieres puedes poner los SP para tratar de mejorarlos.

Comment: He actualizado mi publicación con el procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: ¿En que momento llamas a la función Mostrar, es luego de mostrar el mensaje ""Existe usuario""?

Comment: Ese SP tampoco tiene sentido.. esta devolviendo toda la fila, y vos no usas nada de toda esa informacion. Por que en lugar de hasrows no agarras esa info que viene y se la pasas al siguiente SP? la respuesta seria esa...

Comment: En efecto Davlio, en vez de mostrar el mensaje "Existe usuario", voy a cargar una form, con la información de la función Mostrar()